# How to assign role to user in Registration Controller and its view with Rolify and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rolify

I want to have radiobuttongroup to choose role in my view but im not sure how to handle it. I've already setup the gems rolify and devise but Im not sure how to assign roles in view and controller. I've already created roles in console. I want to make sure that there isn't any exploits when choosing role. For example, if the person tries to change role name from browser and assign that to himself(e.g. admin), that would be a big problem.

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    super
  end

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :email, :terms_of_service])
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
  validates :terms_of_service, :allow_nil => false, :acceptance => true

end
```

**part of view for registration**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, :role => "form", url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label t('label.user.form_content.firstname') %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control text-center" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label t('label.user.form_content.lastname') %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname, :class => "form-control text-center" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label t('label.user.form_content.email') %><br/>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "form-control text-center" %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label t('label.user.form_content.password') %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control text-center" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label t('label.user.form_content.password_confirmation') %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(Must be same with password)</em><br/>
        <% end %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control text-center" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to manage complex functionality with rolify, I got a quite good solution for roles validation inside the User model, I'll leave a link in case you want to check it out.

[Rolify: Validate roles with complex functionality inside the User model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963609/rolify-validate-roles-depending-on-the-roles-being-added/43008942#43008942)

Also, I am adding the roles after user registration inside the registrations_controller, I'll leave another link showing how to do this:

[Adding Role dynamically through Form USing Rolify along with Devise and Cancan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055872/adding-role-dynamically-through-form-using-rolify-along-with-devise-and-cancan)

Hope this helps!